# Verifying if a set is a compact set

Tags: calculus, compactness

I have the following sets and I need to determine which are compact:
$$
A = \{(x,y)| x^{2}+ y^{3} \leqslant 10\}
$$
$$
B = \{(x,y)| x^{2}+ y^{4} \leqslant 10\}
$$
$$
C = \{|x^{2} - 3y|: |x| \leqslant 1, 0\leqslant y \leqslant 1 \} 
$$

my thoughts:
A is non bounded but closed so is non compact.
B And C are both closed and bounded so they are compact sets.

Am I wrong? right? why?

Comment: You are right, $A$ is not bounded, however  $B$ a nd $C$ are bounded. As all the above sets are closed in  $\mathbb{R}^2$ then $B$ and  $C$ are the compact sets.

Comment: You are correct. For the sake of being precise though, you should mention that this follows from the Heine-Borel theorem, as there are spaces in which compact is not equivalent to closed and bounded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right, $A$ is not bounded, and $B,C$ are both bounded and closed.

However, if that would be your answer, you would be lucky to get 20% of all possible points on an exam. You need to prove both that $A$ is unbounded (for example, by finding a sequence in $A$ that is unbounded, or a line) and that $B$ and $C$ are closed and bounded.